# How to add "annotate" data into query with several "values" with django models?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

**Example model**:

```
class A(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True, default=make_uuid, editable=False)
    b = models.IntegerField()
```

**Goal**:
I need to get list which would contain `id`, `b` and `same_b_total`.

e.g. following quetyset returns:

```
a = list(models.Cell.objects.all().values("b").annotate(same_b_total=Count("b")))
print(a)  # [{"b": 1, "same_b_total": 5}, {"b": 2, "same_b_total": 3}]
```

When I add `id` into  `.values("b", "id")` it return list with followind data

```
[{'b': 1, 'id': '<some uuid>', 'same_b_total': 1}, {'b': 1, 'id': '<some uuid2>', 'same_b_total': 1}, {'b': 2, 'id': '<some uuid3>', 'same_b_total': 1}, ...]
```

**How to change query to receive correct `same_b_total` for each record?** Like:

```
[{'b': 1, 'id': '<some uuid>', 'same_b_total': 5}, {'b': 1, 'id': '<some uuid2>', 'same_b_total': 5}, {'b': 2, 'id': '<some uuid3>', 'same_b_total': 3}, ...]
```

Table example:
id(uuid)| b 
 
uuid-1 | 1 
uuid-2 | 1 
uuid-3 | 2 
uuid-4 | 1 
uuid-5 | 1 
uuid-6 | 1 
uuid-7 | 2 
uuid-8 | 2

Comment: how `b` and `same_b_total` is related? Can you give us some real example scenario?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu added table example. `same_b_total ` reflect total count of same `b`. There is 5 `b` with value = 1 and 3 `b` with value = 2

Comment: So, how do you expect the output to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation

Using the combination of `OuterRef` and `Subquery` is what you are looking for.
For a specific integer value for the field of `b` you need to get the count of all existing rows. By replacing the specific integer value with `OuterRef('b')` the result will convert to a subquery. (instead of normal queryset)

Note that `sub` is a subquery and does not exist on its own.

```
sub = A.objects.filter(b=OuterRef('b')).values('b').annotate(same_b_count=Count('id'))
```

We need to inject `sub` into another query. Getting some help from [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/) about combination of `Subquery` and `Outerref` results in:

```
A.objects.annotate(same_b_count=Subquery(sub.values('same_b_count'))).values('id', 'b', 'same_b_count')
```

### Conclusion

Combining two snippets from explanation:

```
sub = A.objects.filter(b=OuterRef('b')).values('b').annotate(same_b_count=Count('id'))
A.objects.annotate(same_b_count=Subquery(sub.values('same_b_count'))).values('id', 'b', 'same_b_count')
```

will result in the output of:

```
<QuerySet [{'id': 1, 'b': 1, 'same_b_count': 3}, {'id': 2, 'b': 1, 'same_b_count': 3}, {'id': 3, 'b': 1, 'same_b_count': 3}, {'id': 4, 'b': 3, 'same_b_count': 1}, {'id': 5, 'b': 4, 'same_b_count': 2}, {'id': 6, 'b': 4, 'same_b_count': 2}, {'id': 7, 'b': 6, 'same_b_count': 1}]>
```